# Updating Child Component When Parent Component is Updated in Vue Js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My project has one parent and child component. Parent component has one state and I want to increase it in a time interval. Child component inherits the state and prints value on console in a time interval. My problem is child component gets the state value only when it is first created. It doesn't get updated.

Expected Output: 0 1 2 ...

My Output: 0 0 0 ...

How can I update the child component when I change the state of the parent component. I tried updated() and watch in the child component with putting log in there. It doesn't enter those places at all. My code is shown below. Can you help?

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <ChildComponent :state="state"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ChildComponent from './components/ChildComponent.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    ChildComponent
  },
  data() {
    return {
      state: 0,
    }
  },
  setup(){
    setInterval(function () {
      if(this.state == null){
        this.state = 0
      }
      this.state = this.state + 1
    }, 1000);
  },
}
</script>
```

ChildComponent.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>

export default {
  name: 'ChildComponent',
  props: ["state"],
  created() {
    setInterval(function () {
      console.log(this.state)
    }.bind(this), 1000);
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `this` inside `setup()`, but during setup, `this` is undefined. So the problem isn't in your child component, it's your interval not updating a responsive property on your parent.

Combining Options API with a setup function tends to cause these mistakes, I would suggest to either go full setup function or full Options API.

Here is a [playground using setup function](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)